# Can not create migration (Laravel Framework 9.17.0)

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu-20.04, laravel-9, laravel-migrations

I want to connect the MySQL database to the Laravel project without XAMPP (Using Ubuntu 22.04).
I created a database called my_project and added it to.env file
[image]

Up next to create migrations I used artisan command: `php artisan migrate`.
As an output it returned

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = my_database and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

[image]

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: can you connect to your mysql-server using `mysql -u root -p` and without entering any password?

Comment: No, I actually created a new DB user. I changed db_username and db_password accordingly. But it returns the same output message.

Comment: So you can't connect to mysql via the command line using either the `root` or your new `user` credentials?

Comment: @Peppermintology there is no problem with connecting to sql with root or new user. I can work with sql properly. Problem with output which return after php artisan migrate. id do no what is the problem. First i though maybe there problem with ports but sql server runs on the 3306 which is tated in .env

Comment: Does the user have the correct privileges configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, my dad found the answer to my problem :D
problem was in giving my database user grant only for localhost.
However, it needs to be granted so it can be connected from any IP.

```
CREATE USER 'amir'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try cleaning the cache by doing

```bash
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: Tried already. Didn't help.